# How to get current project location when I developing a Eclipse plugin to create a project within another project.

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, m2e

I'd like to create a sub-proejct in a proejct like M2E can create a maven module within a maven project when on focus a maven project and right click to create a maven module.

But I don't know how to get the current project location which I clicked.
I use the

```
 WizardNewProjectCreationPage newProject = new WizardNewProjectCreationPage();
 URI location = newProject.getLocationURI();
```

Through this I can set a location by my self.
But I want to get the current project location like m2e do.
Hope someone can help me,Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even though Maven support projects within project (also known as modules), this is not supported by Eclipse. In Eclipse, all projects *must* be top-level entries in the workspace.